# Secure Class: Passlock enabled

Tags: java, android, security

I'm a bit new to android app development. In this code, I'm trying to see if a lock pattern is enabled when users log on to their phone. I'm getting an error here" `int lockPatternEnable = Settings.Secure.getInt(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED);`, and I'm getting red, error lines under the words `secure` is this because I have to delcare the secure class? Any help  would be appreciated.

```
    package com.example.phonesecurityassessment;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.media.audiofx.BassBoost.Settings;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    int lockPatternEnable = Settings.Secure.getInt(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED);
    if (lockPatternEnable==1)
    {
        //lock pattern enabled
    }
    if (lockPatternEnable==0)
    {
        //lock pattern disabled
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm getting red, error lines under the words secure is this because I have to delcare the secure class?

No, you are getting the error lines because you have the wrong `import` for `Settings`. You want `android.provider.Settings`, not `android.media.audiofx.BassBoost.Settings`.